# How to avoid that FOSUserBundle redirect to /login when error bad credential

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

In my application the login box is integreted into my current page. It works fine unless the user make a mistake in its username/password association.

Then the login page is render and this page is not integrated in my website (while I would like to have the login box with the error message like "*bad credential*" into the layout).

How could I do so that the bad credential is delivered on the currrent page? I do not want to be redirected to www.myWebSite/login but to the current page where an inbox where user can logged in.

In my code I ve only overrided "*login.html.twig*" so that it doesn't extends any layout and can be integrated in my current page (*Layout.html.twig*) with a simple:

```
  {{ render(controller("FOSUserBundle:Security:login"))   }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use ajax to authenticate or listen to login failure event

services.yml

```
login_failure_handler:
    class:  'App\UserBundle\Handler\LoginFailureHandler'
    arguments:  [ '@router', '@security.context' ]
    tags:
        - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```

LoginFailureHandler.php

```
class LoginFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{

    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\Router */
    protected $router;

    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext */
    protected $security;

    /**
     * @param Router $router
     * @param SecurityContext $security
     */
    public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContext $security) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    /**
     * This is called when an interactive authentication attempt fails. This is
     * called by authentication listeners inheriting from
     * AbstractAuthenticationListener.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AuthenticationException $exception
     *
     * @return Response The response to return, never null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        // if AJAX login
        if ( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {

            $array = array( 'success' => false, 'message' => $exception->getMessage() ); // data to return via JSON
            $response = new Response( json_encode( $array ) );
            $response->headers->set( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );

            return $response;

            // if form login
        } else {

            // set authentication exception to session
            $request->getSession()->set(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);

            return new RedirectResponse( $this->router->generate( 'your_route' ) );
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your *security.yml* file under *app/config*.

Look for this code:

```
form_login:
    provider:               fos_userbundle
    login_path:             fos_user_security_login
```

And change the *login_path* according to your need,
e.g.:

```
login_path:    /
```

Answer (score -1):

You can catch the error and show it your view :

Controller example :

```
public function loginAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return $this->render('your_bundle:login.html.twig', array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
```

And then show it in your view :

`{{ error.message }`

If you mean that modifying login.html.twig in FOSUserBundle, you must add this :

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
{% if error %}
<div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig#L7

Comment: actually my probleme is that it redirect to the /login page... while I would like to stay on the current page.